# Website problems on iphone

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile

I've got a website with Div's that have a width of 100%. 
This all works, however, when I open the webpage on an iPhone, the div's are not 100% of the width.

Here's a photo of how it looks like on my iPhone:

[image]

The dark-gray is the color of the body.

you can find the beginning of this website at [creemersa.be/Ontwerp2/index.html](http://creemersa.be/Ontwerp2/index.html)

BTW: thoughts/comments on my design are very welcome. I am still a beginner :-)
edit: I also just noticed that my footer isn't displayed well.

thanks

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: This is a CSS problem, I'm sure. Please post the CSS that you're referencing.

Comment: Actually You have the same problem also with Chrome (and I think any other browser) when you resize the window and make it smaller. I guess you change `div` properties when your window get smaller. What do you apply for mobile versions?

Comment: you're right. I just noticed aswell. As for now, I use nothing for mobile versions. I have no experience with mobile websites yet. I think it still looks decent on mobile devices, except for the problem with the divs. I've been browsing my css for an hour now, but can't find anything wrong..

Comment: I don't have mobile versions of my sites either but they scale down perfectly on iOS.  We'll need to see your CSS.  Please post code within your question so it remains useful long after you fix your demo page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from:

```
<div class="wrapper">...</div>
<div class="incontent">...</div>
<div class="incontent2">...</div>
```

Try to add to this three `div` the property `width: 100%`.

```
.wrapper, .incontent, .incontent2 { width: 100%; }
```

I also think you should set the padding: of the `incontent div` to 0:

```
.incontent { padding: 0; }
```

**UPDATE:** the reason why you should put the padding to 0 is that the padding is added to the element width which is set to 100%, therefore the final width will be **100%+padding**. To format correctly the content you should work on the children elements.

Comment: That is weird cause with Chrome Developer Tools if I set the width to 100% it works for me. But remember to change this in your CSS file!! You have set some static values which are no longer good when you have a smaller window.

Comment: @Arnout try to use this Style Sheet: [palliovik.css](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4832939/palliovik.css). It's exactly the same with yours, I've just modified the width of this three elements as I told you.

Comment: You're right, this works. But that's not really what I want to do:
I've got 4 div's: top, content, content2 and bottombar. Those 4 div's have a width of 100%. In those div's,  there are divs that contain the content(wrapper for top, incontent for content and incontent2 for content2).  Those div's should in the center of the screen and should not have a width of 100%. 
Maybe it's a weird layout, but it seemed the best solution for me. Top, content, content2 and bottombar have a width of 100%, so why would this not work? :/

Comment: Actually it's all about your CSS and your structure. You have to know that because of your structure you can't maintain everything like this when the size of your window is smaller. You should change your style and structure once the window is resized. I'm woorking now on your css on the `content2` and `incontent2` elements defining a `min-width` to avoid those kind of problems so that you may have an idea, but you should take a piece of paper and define your structure for dektop and mobile versions. Also be careful when you use `padding` instead of `margin`, read about their behaviour.

Comment: Here is the modified css: [palliovik.css](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4832939/palliovik.css). Please, check the `content2` and `incontent2` elements and try to understand the modification I made and try to apply them on the other elements.

Comment: thanks for your help, I do understand the changes you made but they still don't solve the problem. Even with a min-width, it stays the same. Also, when applying a width of 70% (instead of pixels) to incontent, it's still not solved. When viewing on a small screen, the width stays the amount of pixels that I gave to incontent..

Comment: That's because you have to do the same to `content/incontent` and to `wrapper`. You need to apply this structure to your entire site. That's why I told you to draw everything on a paper so you have a better idea of your structure and apply the same rules everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check that all elements do not have a defined width larger than the device you are designing for. Use percentages in your CSS whenever possible. A width of say 900px will stretch the viewport. For iPhone this is **320px**.

Comment: This is not a useful answer at all.  My properly constructed sites use various fixed widths starting at 900 pixels and they all scale down perfectly in iOS.

Comment: It's useful because the question is about using percentages. If some elements are pixel based and others are percentages, it will cause the effect in the image above. Regardless of how you choose to design your sites, iOS does a bang-up job of displaying everything.

Comment: IMHO, any answer that makes such generalizations without much explanation deserves not to be taken seriously.  It's just not good advice when iOS can display full size websites perfectly fine.